# How to create touch interactive charts for android

Tags: android, charts, interactive

I need charts for my application where the user use gesture to redraw the charts in android. Could you suggest any charting API,tool or software which supports.

Comment: There are graph libraries you can include (http://www.java4less.com/charts/chart.php?info=android) but as for the gestures you may have to do this youself.

Answer (score 4):

[ZingCharts](http://www.zingchart.com) is a javascript library that can be included in an HTML page which was loaded into a WebView. You can pass the data in JSON format to the javascript function. Graphs are animated, interactive, eye-catchy and fast as well. I used evaluation version and it worked well.

Answer (score 2):

Check out AndroidPlot: http://androidplot.com

Like the previous poster said, you'll have to implement the gesture/keypress event handling yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at AChartEngine: http://www.achartengine.org

Apache 2 license, open-source and easy to use.

Comment: achartengine is not touch interactive

Answer (score 0):

TeeChart for Android supports gestures in "tools", like for example the DragPoint tool enables touch-dragging of chart points.  Other tools include Zoom, Scroll, 3D Rotate, tooltips, etc.

http://www.steema.com/entry/63/TeeChart_Java_Chart_for_Android_now_available