# Animations for Charts using Google chart API in android

Tags: android, charts, google-visualization

Is it possible to animate the chart obtained from google chart api in android ? If so how can we do that ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a native google chart api for android so no, it is not possible to animate the chart, the last time I used it, I had to generate the URL from java code and display it in a WebView. I think you need to use javascript for animation like this: [animation charts for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2721580/how-to-create-touch-interactive-charts-for-android). Hope it helps

Comment: Can we apply html marquee to charts ?