# Using Google visualization charts for Android

Tags: android, charts, visualization, interactive

I am relatively new to Android, but I am looking to use an interactive charting tool for my application. I have read around in some forums about using Google's charts to display in a webview in my application, but from what I have found this is only displaying the static image. Does anyone know if there is a way to display the chart and have it be interactive also in Android? I am developing in 4.0 so as far as I know it does support SVG. More or less I am just looking for confirmation that this is possible before I dive into attempting to make it work. And any advice on how to do so would be great as well. Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2721580/813951

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [google dynamic Charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/) are interactive when they are shown in a WebView within android.

However the interaction seems to have been more heavily geared toward a PC with a mouse rather than a touch screen. So it is not quite as rich an interaction as it could be on a touch device unfortunately .

Comment: Okay, like when I open a browser in my emulator and view that link I can click on the pie chart and see it interact, but when I do the chart wizard

https://developers.google.com/chart/image/docs/chart_wizard

to create a chart and then display it, it is only a static image. How would I get my application to call the service and create my dynamic chart, then display it?

Comment: press the 'Get started' Button on the page I linked. That'll show you how the example was created. And point you in the direction / resources to show you how to make your own. AFAIK there is no wizard for the interactive charts though, you'll have to mess with the nitty gritty code to make it work.

Comment: Yea I think I might look for an opensource native library like achartengine or something then, seems easier and more functional. Thank you!