# Hours of Service in Android - Step Chart

Tags: android, graph, charts, android-graphview

Here I am trying to implement this kind of Step Line Graph in Android but not able to find better option for how to generate that graph.

I look some links which is similar I want. I am newbie in Android for Graphs/Charts Library.

1. [Graph Image - 1](https://lh4.ggpht.com/NyTmMiNMA82lfey2HnDgKZi-KmMEKCf0cUA7M2SoDlJNRgbmfvB21_6xfvsVVLL2PQ=h900)
2. [Graph Image - 2](http://cdn8.staztic.com/app/a/2050/2050281/comiddlproject-371839-1-s-307x512.jpg)

Is it possible same graphs in android?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2721580/how-to-create-touch-interactive-charts-for-android

Comment: I got the same graph in Android using this library. https://code.google.com/p/achartengine/

Comment: can u please add a code snippet for the chart u imnplemented? or Please guide  to make the design and functionality for the hours of service in android.

Comment: @PrSI did you achieve this?